# Javascript gallery, adding images with "for" loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gallery

I'm creating gallery in my project, but i don't want to spam clear html  and repeat it 20 times in my code. I want to create loop in javascript to get the numbers of images from my folder and later add this into one div. I've created code but i don't know how to step it. 
Code:

```
function addingImages() {

    for (var i = 0; i <= ***; i++) {
        var image = document.createElement("img");
        image.setAttribute("src", "images/1.jpg");
        document.querySelector(".gallery").appendChild(image);
    }
}
```

*** - i don't know what should be there. and i know i need variable to increment later numbers of images like 1.jpg , 2.jpg, 3.jpg etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop from 1 to 20, so set loop count to 20. Then use index from loop in setAttribute function like this:

```
   function addingImages() {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        var image = document.createElement("img");
        image.setAttribute("src", "images/" + i + ".jpg");
        document.querySelector(".gallery").appendChild(image);
   }
}
```

Comment: That works yeah, actually i've been thinking about it but that's not the way i would like to go. I need dynamic code. I mean, later in two months i would like to add images to my folder and not changing numbers in code. Do you know what's my point ?? 
i <= Something.length 
... + something.length + ... 
But i don't know how to read number of my images :/

Comment: Well, this is not possible with JavaScript alone. You need to create a server method that counts images and invoke that method via javascript ajax call. Then get the result and loop desired amount of iterations.

Comment: I felt that I taking hard question and this cannot be done in pure js only. Ok but at least i know now :) I'm glad that it works actually, i need to remember to change my iterator always when i will be adding some images. Thank You for help!

Answer (score 0):

With Jquery, you can also use this:

```
function addImages(img_count) {
   var images='';
   for (var i = 1; i <= img_count; i++) {
    image = '<img src="images/'+i+'.jpg">';
   }
   $(".gallery").html(image);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this jquery(Ajax) function Instead of for loop because you need to check images inside your folder before include it in the gallery
        $.ajax({
      url: "images/",
      success: function(data){
         $(data).find("a:contains(.jpg)").each(function(){
            var filename = this.href.replace(window.location.host,          "").replace("http://", "");
            $("gallery").append("");
         });
      }
    });